# FirebaseUI Unclear Image

Tags: android, firebase, android-glide, firebaseui

I'm using firebaseUI to retrieve images into ImageView but the downloaded image in the app is hazy. I tried with different images but it's still hazy.

Here is the code:

```
String val="images/"+id+".jpg";
    StorageReference ref=mStorageRef.child(val);
    Glide.with(this)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(ref)
            .into(imageView);
```

[Hazy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQQYg.png)

Comment: What is the size of the image ? If it is very small it is hazy because of the zoom in.

Comment: I tried with different sizes, It's hazy always - It's clear in its original form when viewed in gallery or laptop.

Comment: Can you post the URL of the image?

Comment: I can't figure out the problem here. The image is hazy when the activity is opened for the first time but it loads again when I return to the activity and is clear this time.

I expect it to be clear in the first instance only.

Comment: Maybe Glide performs some kind of downscaling?